# Dynamic data binding to the repeater or Datalist control, Column-wise

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, repeater

Below `image/output` shows on how the data should be `rendered` considering the `rankID` with the table.

[image]
with the below `demo table` as well

[image]

Now, their will be `4 different rows` which should be bound to the image shown above according to the `RankID [1,2,3,4]` on first slide and then on and on with slides as user clicks on `next navigation`.

For the same to achieve we have used `Repeater control` but the `data is bounded` `row wise` hence decided to use `datalist control` which has a property to bind data columnwise`, still we are not able to do, or else we need to use`multiple or nested repeater/ datalist control`.

Kindly suggest the solution or the way to achieve the same..

Comment: I don't get the question. You can order by `RankID` when fetching the data. Other than that it is a matter of correctly styling the Control with CSS.

Comment: The data is bound same i.e. [same row is bound agan and again]

Comment: @PPB database tables have no order. There's nothing in the data you showed that could help determine which four rows to display. Why not the first two and the last two in the image? If those rows are related by eg a ProductID you should return it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can have full control over the Repeater Contents to create a difference for the first item. See the snippet below.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "<td colspan=\"3\">" : "<td>" %>

                <%# Eval("Description") %>

                <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "</td></tr><tr>" : "</td>" %>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess my requirement is different..i want to bind all first 4 rows from the table to the repeater. Check Rank ID on the table and Image, and when user clicks on next navigation next 4 rows should get bind

Comment: @PPB in other words, you don't have 4 rows. You have *1* parent item with four child entities . Bind the repeater to the *parent* item and add the child items as needed.

Comment: @PPB in any case you'll have to determin which 4 rows to display, either in the query, eg by exposing a ProductID or whatever was used to group and generate the ranking, or in code by splitting the results in groups of four. Bind to those groupings, not the individual items

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you please illustrate with example considering the demo table attached.